# String Compare with 2d array C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm having thoughts about copying a string to a 2d array. I have a 2d char array initialized as `char labels[100][2]` so it's a 100 * 2 array. I would like the first column of every row to contain a string and I know you can't simply assign a string, you must do a string copy. My thinking was I could do:

```
strcpy(labels[1][0],"hi");//The compiler doesn't like this
```

After researching, I saw a idea that you could do:

```
strcopy(labels[1],"hi")
```

I'm curious about this because this `strcpy` is in a `for` loop so I'm gonna have up to ten copies possibly and I didn't know if this would properly copy to the first column only everytime.

Comment: It has `100` arrays each of array of `2` characters. `100*2` is number of characters (elements) in the array `labels`.

Comment: is that what that syntax means, I thought it meant 100 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: I just used "hi" as an example also, the string could be anywhere up to 6 characters

Comment: Rows and columns is one way to visualize it. But yes, it is just an array of 100 arrays of size 2.

Comment: No. Your thought was wrong.

Comment: So if i would like to create an array that can hold 6 characters for a label, and one character for an address would I create labels[10][7]

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do here, but you can't strcpy(char, const char*), correct syntax is strcpy(char*, const char*). Also strcpy copies until null character at the end of const char* string including null character, so for your 2d array to hold bunch of 2 char-long strings, you'd need char labels[100][3] and use strcpy(labels[i], "hi") for i=[0,99]

Comment: I think you should actually do `labels[10][8]` for that. In C, strings have to end with the character '\0' (the null character), so you need the extra space at the end to hold that. Using string literals, such as "hi", will automatically add the null character, so you don't have to worry about it much. You just need to make sure you have room for it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I wanted to create a 2d array that would store 6 characters of a label and another character for the corresponding address which would be stored as a single char. So if i'm understanding right, I could create an array that can hold ten of these elements through labels[10][7] and enough to hold 7 chars.

Comment: Almost there. You have a label of six characters, an address of one character, and the null character, so that is 8 characters total. So you need to declare it as `labels[10][8]`. It might not make as much sense, but it's one of those little things that you have to get used to with C

Comment: I think , I don't understand your question yet. Do you want to fill *row* of that 2D array or you want to fill the first column of that array?

Comment: @haccks I have an label of up to 6 characters and a one character address. I wanted to store them at first I thought just 6 in one column and 1 in the next but as I'm learning, it's not as simple as being able to access one column like labels[0][0] with that column holding a 6 character label and labels[0][1] with that column holding that one character address

Comment: I think you are confused with *row* and *column* (number of rows -> move virtically, number of columns -> move horizontally). Do you want store `a, b, c, d, e, f` in `lables[0][0], labels[0][1],labels[0][2],labels[0][3],labels[0][4],labels[0][5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process a column of a 2D array you can do as;

```
char labels[100][2], (*p)[2], i;
....

for (p = &labels[i]; p < &labels[100]; P++)
    (*P)[i] = //assign a char
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about your statement "you can't simply assign a string".  This is true, but you can assign a pointer to a string literal.  Why not simplify this as follows:

```
char *labels[100];

labels[0] = "hi";
labels[1] = "bye";
labels[2] = "arbitrary-length string literal";
....
```

This is much more straightforward than dealing with 2d arrays, strcpy(), etc.

Also, strcpy() is generally considered [unsafe](http://www.codepolice.org/c/strcpy.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the label+address in a single 7 char string, then the simplest way is:

```
#define MAX_LABELS 100
char labels[MAX_LABELS][7];

// do something with the array
for (int i=0; i<MAX_LABELS; i++) {
   strcpy(labels[i], "label");  // watch for buffer overflow here
   labels[i][6] = (char)i;
}
```

Or, if it doesn't matter if the label and address are in the same string, make the code more readable by using an array of structures:

```
struct LabelStruct {
    char label[6];
    char address[1];
} labels[MAX_LABELS];

// do something with the array
for (int i=0; i<MAX_LABELS; i++) {
    strcpy(labels[i].label, "label");  // watch for buffer overflow here
    labels[i].address = (char)i;
}
```

You didn't say whether you need null-terminated labels or not, but if so, add one more char to the label array.  Also when assigning data to the label, check for overflow (use `strncpy` or similar).